# StringStream input with comma delimited string - know columns apriori

Tags: c++, csv, tokenize, stringstream

I have a csv that I'd like to tokenize line by line with StringStream. The key is that I know apriori what the columns would look like. For example, say I know the file looks like the following

```
StrHeader,IntHeader
abc,123
xyz,456
```

I know ahead of time it is a string column, followed by an int column.

Common approach is to read the file line by line

```
std::string line;
stringstream lineStream;
while (getline(infile, line))   // read line by line
{
    cout << "line " << line << endl;

    lineStream << line;
    string token;
    while(getline(lineStream, token, ','))  // push into vector? this is not ideal
    {
    }
```

I know I can have 2 loops, and have inner loop tokenizes the string based on commas. Lots of sample code on stackoverflow would store the result into a `vector<string>`.

I don't want to do create a new vector every line. Since I know apriori what columns the file would have, can I somehow read directly into a `string` and `int` variable? Like this

```
std::string line;
stringstream lineStream;
while (getline(infile, line))   // read line by line
{
    cout << "line " << line << endl;
    lineStream << line; // DOESNT WORK - tell lineStream we have comma delimited string
    string strValue;
    int intValue;
    lineStream >> strValue >> intValue;   // SO MUCH CLEANER
    // call foo(strValue, intValue);
}
```

The problem above is this line

```
    lineStream << line; // DOESNT WORK - tell lineStream we have comma delimited string
```

From what I could tell, the above code works if the input line is space delimited, not comma delimited.

I have no control over the input. So, simply replacing the "spaces" with "commas" in the original string is not an ideal solution since I don't know if the input already has spaces.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to only read to the delimiter with `std::getline()` and then put that in a string stream for conversion.

```
while (!infile.eof()){
    std::getline(infile, strValue, ',');
    std::getline(infile, line);
    strstr.str(line);
    strstr.clear();
    int intValue;
    strstr >> intValue;
    foo(strValue, intValue);
}
```